# How to extend the Ajax control toolkit

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

ive seen some pages that offer new ajax animations.. can i use those in .NET?? if not, how do you create new ajax animations for .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea on how to do this, but I can point you in the direction that I would take if I ever need to do such thing.

Try to watch some of the [AJAX Videos](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/) on [ASP.NET Website](http://www.asp.net/)

specially video #64 called [Create an ASP.NET AJAX Extender from Scratch?](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-184.aspx)
(15 minutes, 11 seconds)

and here are 2 good reads to accomplish this:

> [Extending JavaScript with ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/EnhancingJavaScriptTutorial.aspx)

and

> [How To: Create an ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit Extender Control to Extend a GridView](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/08/08/creating-an-asp-net-ajax-toolkit-extender-control.aspx)

it might help you see how to extend the asp.net ajax framework